# Force Rapid-Fail Protection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to test some configuration changes on my server to handle my application pool shutting down due to rapid-fail protection kicking in.  What I'm trying to do is configure the "Shutdown Executable" setting to run

```
"appcmd start apppol <myapppool>"
```

after rapid-fail protection stops the app pool.  This is a temporary solution until we actually figure out what the root cause of the problem is.

I wrote a little MVC app that just throws and exception whenever the only controller action is invoked.  When that happens I see the following warning in the event log:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 10/7/2014 10:46:01 AM 
Event time (UTC): 10/7/2014 2:46:01 PM 
Event ID: bba339cfcab74ffe9cb4292c746203c2 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0
```

However, this is not sufficient to cause rapid-fail protection to trigger.  Does anyone knows what causes rapid-failure protection to trigger?  Or better yet how to crash the worker process assciated with an mvc request?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an action that causes a native process failure, such as (apropos) a stack overflow.

```
public class AdminController
{
    [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
    public ActionResult FailHard()
    {
        //StackOverflow
        return FailHard();
    }
}
```

Then just hit /admin/failhard while logged in as an Administrator.

Be very careful if you make that URL live on your production site. It would be wise to build in some protections, like taking a parameter that requires providing today's date to avoid accidental activation.

Comment: What is a body of  FailHard(); Sorry, I see